# TC failures observed for Quorum-2.2.3

Tags: quorum

2 TCs are failing on Big endian system, seems the issue is with the byte ordering only.

1) ethereum/go-ethereum/core/bloombits

2) ethereum/go-ethereum/swarm/storage/feed

Can some one please comment about the significance of these TCs, any critical functionality would be affected if these are neglected?

Comment: Hi, how is this Quorum related?

Comment: Hi @fixanoid,
geth binary is created properly by building Quorum-2.2.3 , getting the above failures when TCs were executed, I have read that Quorum is not supporting big endian systems but your inputs might be helpful for us to decide if we can ignore these failures.

Let me know if I am missing anything.